# PHP: number_format issue

Tags: php

Iv taken over a very old php project that is still currently in use. 
Its a custom "shopping" website.

When a product gets ordered it inserts the money value into the database as a string of integers:

```
2000
```

which then gets outputted as follows:

> R20,00

Using this code

```
echo number_format($order['order_total'] / 100, 2, ",", "");
```

My problem is that if an order gets placed to the value of **R 15 256.00**
The record gets inserted as such:

```
15256
```

and gets outputted to the user as:

> R 152,56

But it should ultimately show like this

> R15, 256.00

I do understand that the problem comes in by dividing the amount by 100 in the above query. If i alter the query then the larger numbers appear fine but the smaller amounts such as R20,00 get shown as R2000,00

Any help would be great.

Comment: you want 152,56 to 15256 ?

Comment: i want it to read 15, 256.00

Comment: So you should remove the `/ 100`?

Comment: @ThomasKekeisen then the 2000 values wont be converted in 20,00. This system is setup strange

Comment: Shouldn't `2000` be represented as `R20.00` to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you PHP's native function [`money_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php), which will format the number as a currency.
Using [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) you can set the appropriate locale.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN'); 
echo money_format('%!i', 15256);
```

This will output:

> 15,256.00

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
echo number_format($order['order_total'] / 100, 2, ".", ",");
```

you can read more about number format [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) .